# What are all the events captured by Websphere JAVA_DUMP_OPTS conditions?

Tags: java, websphere

From the IBM [ref](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.70.doc/diag/tools/dumpagents_env.html), I found there are 6 conditions that can be included in JAVA_DUMP_OPTS properties as follows.

- ANYSIGNAL
- DUMP
- ERROR
- INTERRUPT
- EXCEPTION
- OUTOFMEMORY

But I couldn't find what are all the events that will be captured by each of these condition. The list of all possible events are available [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.70.doc/diag/tools/dumpagents_events.html).

Can someone help me out to map each of these events to their corresponding conditions which will capture those events in a heap dump or core dump?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions specified in `JAVA_DUMP_OPTS` maps to OS signals rather than dump events (except OUTOFMEMORY).

For Linux, the mapping is as follows:

- **EXCEPTION**: SIGTRAP, SIGILL, SISEGV, SIGFPE, SIGBUS, SIGXFSZ
- **INTERRUPT**: SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGHUP
- **ERROR**: SIGABRT
- **DUMP**: SIGQUIT

Full list of Signal Mappings for `JAVA_DUMP_OPTS`: [Signal mappings](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.zos.71.doc/diag/tools/dumpagents_signals.html).

This IBM Technote has more details on the signals part: [What is a signal and why does this matter for WebSphere Application Server?](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003858).